# Bash - loop through subdirectories are including files too

Tags: bash, console

I have `clean-logs.sh` in `/var/log/fleet3/zok/` which following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /var/log/fleet3/zok/*/ ; do
    cd $(dir)
    pwd #rm -rf *
    cd ..
done
```

and that file is iteratting too, not only subdirectories... And yes, I have subdirectories in that directory and files in that subdirectories. What is wrong? I want only loop through subdirectories.

## Edit:

When I was executing script, that was output:

```
[user@machine zok]# ./clean-logs.sh
./clean-logs.sh: line 4: cd: clean-logs.sh: Not a directory
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
/var/log/fleet3/zok
```

terdon's answer resolved my problem, I was using wrong `$(variable)` instead `${variable}`

Comment: Please add a (short) example to your question, showing what is happening and identifying what you want to happen in this example. I don't understand "_that file is iterating too_" because there are no files referenced in your script

Comment: Assuming your commented out code was what you were actually trying to do, just `rm -rf /var/log/fleet3/zok/*/` would delete all the subdirectories (and their contents) in `/zok/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what your issue is, your script will only iterate over directories. That is ensured by the last `/` in `for dir in /var/log/fleet3/zok/*/`. However, you do have a very serious problem, since you have misunderstood the `$(foo)` construct.

`$(foo)` will run the *command* `foo` and then return its output. For example:

```
$ echo $(pwd)
/home/terdon
```

You seem to want to use the variable, not execute it, so your `cd` command should be:

```
cd "$dir"
```

And not `cd $(dir)`.

Also, if you want to delete every subdirectory of `/var/log/fleet3/zok/`, you don't need a loop or a script, you can simply do `rm -rf /var/log/fleet3/zok/*/`. Or, if you just really want the loop for some reason, you could simplify to:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /var/log/fleet3/zok/*/ ; do
    rm -rf "$dir"/*
done
```

Comment: Hmm, that is weird :D I always use variables by `$(variable)`, and on another machine, script is working good. Is not iterating over files, is only `cd`-ing to subdirectories. But now I trying with `"$variable"` and now all is ok :) Thank you!

And I want delete all files from subdirectories, but subdirectories must be preserved, so I was looping through all subdirectories.

Comment: I was using `$(variable)` because I learned, that if I want do e.g. `mv $file $file_suffix` this is wrong.

Comment: Ohhh, I know what I do wrong ><.... I used `$(variable)` instead `${variable}`... Thanks all you guys!